# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index from helper function to split data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, typeerror

I am trying to understand why this is receiving the **TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index** in this helper function, specifically when it starts at line

```
X_left = X[left_mask]
```

```
def split_data(self, X, y, feature, value):
        left_mask = X[:, feature] <= value.astype(X.dtype)
        right_mask = X[:, feature] > value.astype(X.dtype)
        X_left = X[left_mask]
        y_left = y[left_mask]
        X_right = X[right_mask]
        y_right = y[right_mask]
        return X_left, y_left, X_right, y_right
```

This function is called from another function here:

```
X_left, X_right, y_left, y_right = [], [], [], []
if isinstance(X, list):
            X = np.asarray(X)

        num_features = X.shape[1]
        best_feature = None
        best_value = None
        best_score = float("inf")
        best_X_left, best_y_left, best_X_right, best_y_right = None, None, None, None
        
        for feature in range(num_features):
            for value in np.unique(X[:, feature]):
                X_left, y_left, X_right, y_right = self.split_data(X, y, feature, value)
                score = self.gini_index(y_left, y_right)
                if score < best_score:
                    best_feature = feature
                    best_value = value
                    best_score = score
                    best_X_left, best_y_left, best_X_right, best_y_right = X_left, y_left, X_right, y_right
        return best_feature, best_value, best_X_left, best_y_left, best_X_right, best_y_right
```

where X is the data containing all attributes and y are the labels

I have tried printing out each of the values to understand what is happening, but I am still learning about how Python works.

Here are the imports as well:

```
#export
import csv
import numpy as np  # http://www.numpy.org
import ast
from datetime import datetime
from math import log, floor, ceil
import random
```

Comment: Yes adding print statements to see what `X` and `left_mask` is the right debugging step.  My guess us `X` is a list, not an array.

Comment: This is odd, because in  `X[:, feature]` behaves as an array, and the caller's `isinstance` should have converted any lists to array.

Comment: @hpaulj correct, when I print X, it is an array shown